# Open generated text as savable .txt file in new tab

Tags: javascript, browser, save, text-files

I'd like to generate a text document of the following string:

```
const rawText = `Today is ${new Date()}`;

openInNewTabWithDefaultFilename(rawText, "TodaysDate.txt");
```

I've seen some stuff about how to open a new tab and set the content:

```
var newTab = window.open();
newTab.document.title = "Todays Date";
newTab.document.body.innerHTML = `Today is ${new Date()}`;
```

But this opens up as a tab with text, not as a text file.  I want users to be able to save the page as a text file simply.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bunch of research, this seems to be as good as it gets.

You can not open text in a new tab that is savable, let alone has a default filename.

The only way to generate a text file that can be viewed and then saved is to use data urls, but Google has mis-appropriately deemed the entirety of them a security threat (certain ones are, text/plain absolutely is not).

The best work-around I've discovered is to create two buttons/links, one which downloads the file and another for viewing it.

**If you want to pre-generate your files, you can do this**

```html
<a id="DownloadTextFile" download="TodaysDate.txt">Download</a>
<a id="ViewTextFile">View</a>

<script>
const blob = new Blob([`Today is ${new Date()}`], { type: "text/plain" });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

const view = document.getElementById("ViewTextFile");
const download = document.getElementById("DownloadTextFile");
view.href = download.href = url;
</script>
```

---

**If you want to generate on click (example won't work due to missing StackOverflow iframe permissions)**

```js
const byId = (id) => document.getElementById(id);

byId("ViewTextFile").addEventListener("click", () => {
  serveTextFile(`Today is ${new Date()}`);
})

byId("DownloadTextFile").addEventListener("click", () => {
  serveTextFile(`Today is ${new Date()}`, "TodaysDate.txt");
});

function serveTextFile(text, downloadAs) {
  const blob = new Blob([text], { type: "text/plain"});
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  const domNode = document.createElement('a');
  downloadAs && (domNode.download = downloadAs);
  !downloadAs && (domNode.target = "_blank");
  domNode.href = url;
  domNode.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(domNode);
  domNode.click();
  document.body.removeChild(domNode);
}
```

```html
<div id="DownloadTextFile">Download</div>
<div id="ViewTextFile">View</div>
```