# How can I download a .txt file from url?

Tags: javascript

I have a function to download files:

```
downloadFile(url, filename) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    link = null;
},
```

This function work with `.csv` and `.xlsx` files. When a user click to a button `.txt` file supposed to download too. If it is a txt file nothing happens.

I add this this two lines to code;

```
    if(url.includes(".txt")){
      link.target = '_blank';
    }
```

It looks like this;

```
downloadFile(url, filename) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = filename;
    if(url.includes(".txt")){
      link.target = '_blank';
    }
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    link = null;
},
```

When a user want to download the txt file it opens on a tab of browser and they need to right click and save the file over and over again.

For example this link;
[Example txt file](https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/sample-text-file.txt)

So how can I make the URL ending with `.txt` extension downloadable?

This solution tried but it is not link, it just content. [Not Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916191/download-data-url-file)

Comment: That code works just fine to download a `.txt` for me with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I am trying on VUE.js but logics are same. Do you think it cause the problem? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: I don't use Vue.js. Assuming it stays out of the way of the above, though, I would expect that to matter. (It wouldn't with React.)

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nueagyv6/) I try here but result same. If operating system cause, users have windows, mac, linux. All have same feedback @T.J.Crowder.

Comment: @MuratDemir [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a?retiredLocale=nl#attr-download) "_`download` only works for [same-origin URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), or the `blob:` and `data:` schemes_". Is your `url` on the same origin?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64998717/open-generated-text-as-savable-txt-file-in-new-tab

Comment: @Ivar No, it come from an api.

Comment: Omg, it works well. Thank you @Ivar. You can write an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @MuratDemir [No need to repeat answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). :) You should have the option to accept the question as a duplicate.